# How to switch to English in BusyBox?

Tags: boot, language-support, busybox

my computer goes to busybox and (apparently) the keyboard is stuck on hebrew, therefore, i can not enter lowercase english letters and hebrew coms out as squares, how can I switch to English?
[image]

Comment: all I could find was using a USB English keyboard or running whatever you need to from a live USB.